# Taking response from grpc in clojure

Tags: clojure, grpc, grpc-java

I am working with some clojure and need to call a grpc based endpoint.

```
ExampleGrpcRequest {
   string name = 1
}

ExampleGrpcResponse {
  repeated string Books = 1
}

Book {
 string name = 1
 int pages = 2
}

service ExampleService {
  rpc GetBook(ExampleGrpcRequest) returns (ExampleGrpcResponse) {}
}
```

This is my grpc request/response struct. I want to parse the response from an api call in Clojure and map it to another object. I even tried searching some resources but couldn't find much on the same lines.

- This is core clojure based question
- grpc proto used are based on java
- getBooks() would return an a list of books.

Edit:
*Making my Question a bit clear-*

- How do I parse grpc response in clojure? Is there any efficient way to do it? I checked out some blogs & didn't understood.
  As I am new to clojure & grpc, I want to undestand is this similar to
  how we parse a grpc response in Java? i.e.
  If I would want to parse a grpc response from a java client-
  I would do something like:

> ExampleGrpcResponse.GetBooks().get(0).getName();
> ExampleGrpcResponse.GetBooks().get(0).GetPage();

Comment: Is this Clojure or ClojureScript (the question is tagged with both)?  Are you using a (Java?) library to interact with gRPC?  If so, please provide more details.

Comment: Does `.getBooks()` return an iterable object? If so, then you can use any of Clojure's built-in functions for iterating over them like `for`, `map`, `reduce`, etc.

Comment: I have a hard time to find the actual question here.  Could you please add the code you have actually tried and how it failed? Is the GRPC part not working? Or do you have problems with the Response object?

Comment: @cfrick - updated the question, hope it is better now.

Comment: @Jeremy aaa I guess I got what you are trying to say! thanks.

Comment: Yes, it works the same as with Java.  Check out how interop works from clojure. https://clojure.org/reference/java_interop